# How to use TIME datatype in SQL Server 2008 and C#?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-3.0, sqldatatypes

I am developing a web application with C# & SQL Server 2008.

I have a data reader which reads the column `PlayTime`, defined as `TIME` datatype.

I want to write a function that returns `PlayTime`'s value.

```
private static Timespan GetTime(IDataReader rdr, string columnName)`
{
    int index = rdr.GetOrdinal(columnName);

    if (rdr.IsDBNull(index))
    {
      return ; // Here I want to return null or zero 
    }

    return (TimeSpan)rdr[index];
}
```

1. Am I right using `Timespan` for time data type?
2. How to return `null` if datareader value is nothing?

Best Regards,

RedsDevils

Comment: Have you considered returning a nullable TimeSpan

Comment: Like you said, I need to put "Timespan?"  , can return null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
private static TimeSpan? GetTime(IDataReader rdr, string columnName)
{
    int index = rdr.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    if (rdr.IsDBNull(index))
    {
      return null;
    }
   return (TimeSpan)rdr[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use nullable Timespan

```
 private static Nullable<TimeSpan> GetTime(IDataReader rdr, string columnName)
        {
            int index = rdr.GetOrdinal(columnName);
            if (rdr.IsDBNull(index))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return (Nullable<TimeSpan>)rdr[index];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. In Table, that column "PlayTime" is "time" DataType: I don't want Date. Like you show it will contain date, right?

Comment: Do I need to add "Nullable" at return rdr[index], it's only need type conversion?